# How to download file from URL in React without opening preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

So far I have already seen a lot of questions where this type of question were asked but none of works in my case.

I would like to tell you in the first place is **The Server Side is Not Mine!** means the URL were
from another source!

What I've tried is -

---

I have tried to add `download` attr in the anchor tag or `<a href="urlhere" download></a>` It will just open a new page with preview
also tried with react `Link` none of them worked!

---

And tried with these libraries [`file-saver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver), [`js-file-downloader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-downloader),
same issues!

---

when trying one of those things I got an error saying -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'urlOfDownloadingfile' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource.
```

I think because the server-side is not controlled by me so that's why it is happening!

Is there any way I can solve this issue!

Any help will be always appreciated!